# Auto generate well formated number using php

Tags: php, mysql

I create a payment slip and it has voucher number, so voucher number text box is read only. I want to generate unique auto increment formatted number like this one `"LN/SSS/01"` and echo in my read only text box. How can i do it?

Comment: Create your number and write to DB. Set unique field in DB and regenerate number if it's exists.

Comment: but i dont know how to generate a number like this format. i am newest for PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can use a column with Auto Increment such as id for achieving the same. And then use that col for achiving your desired result.

Somthing like this:-

```
SELECT concat('LN/SSS/',id) 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Then assign this value to your text box.